# DESCRIBE TABLE Equivalent for Apache Ignite

Tags: python, sql, apacheignite

I am looking to get the column names and the data types for my Apache Ignite tables. Is there a SQL query that can be used to accomplish this? Maybe an equivalent to the `DESCRIBE TABLE` command?

If this is not possible using SQL, can it be done using the Python driver for Apache Ignite: `pyignite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get the columns and data types of tables in Apache Ignite by using the `SYS.TABLE_COLUMNS` system table.

The query is as follows,

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TYPE
FROM SYS.TABLE_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = <table_name>
```

Note: The data types returned are Java object types.